# Lingotek Translation showing interim status for every translation

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I am working with lingotek module in Drupal 8 and I am following all the procedures but still facing some issues on local setup.
The automatic translation is taking place and it is displaying `interim status` every time after the translation is done, which is a state where incomplete translations can be published.

So, the translation part is not fully completed. I have followed the steps on fresh installation but still getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the translation is not complete. 
This could happen because you have a pending review phase in your workflow.
What happens if you use the "Check target status" operation?

PS: As @user73757 said, it's easier to get support in the Lingotek module issue queue.

Comment: Hi, When i use the "check upload progress" operation after it shows source uploaded. It displays Japanese- in progress, in which my case i am translating English to Japanese. After this, I request for Japanese translation and then again i check progress of Japanese translation and it shows Japanese -ready for download. but yet again after clicking download Japanese translation it shows interim status where translation is incomplete and published.